# Bash: Outputting time's stderr to new file every in iteration of a loop

Tags: bash

Practically I am just trying to output time's stderr to a different file every time the loop runs, here is my code, I am unsure why it does not work when I have the $i.
This is my code currently.

```
(time for i in {1..5}
do
 #some command
done) > temp.txt 2>> $i.txt
```

This code below works but doesn't have a separate file for each iteration.

```
(time for i in {1..5}
do
 #some command
done) > temp.txt 2>> output.txt
```

Comment: you are piping it to output.txt file everytime. you should do something like output+var.txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `time` command inside the loop, since the `$i` variable doesn't exist outside the loop.

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    time some command 2>>"$i.txt"
done > temp.txt
```

Comment: Oh of course thank you, but I am trying to time the execution of the whole loop.

Comment: How can you time the execution of the whole loop but put the results in 5 different files?